Dynamic values into pipeline resource branch value
I want to provide every time different branch name for download artifacts in azure devops. I have code like this resources:
pipelines:
  - pipeline: Pipeline_name # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: Pipeline_name  # Name of the triggering pipeline
    branch: ${{ parameters.releaseBranch }}

I want to provide name of the branch into parameter or variable group in azure devops and than using this while donwloading artifcats. Unfortunetly i get an error every time, that specific build wasnt found from branch which I provided. I found only way is to hardcoded branch name into yaml file and can not provide this like runtime paramters. Have you any idea how to do this?
I just tried hard coded into yaml and it works, but there is a lot of changes in case of diffrent artifacts on diffrent branches so i need to have flexible providing the branch name.

I don't think you can set these values dynamically.

I am afraid that we are not able to use Parameters/Variables in Pipeline Resource -> Branch field.
It currently only supports hard-coding branch name in Pipeline Resource.

provide every time different branch name for download artifacts in azure devops.

For a workaround, you can use the Download Pipeline Artifacts task or Download Build Artifacts task in Azure DevOps to download artifacts.
In this case, we can define the branch name via Variables/Parameters in Pipeline tasks.
For example:
jobs:
- job: deploy_windows_x86_agent
  steps:
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: 'projectname'
      pipeline: 'pipelineID or PipelineName'
      buildVersionToDownload: 'latestFromBranch'
      branchName: '${{ parameters.releaseBranch }}'
      downloadType: 'single'
      artifactName: 'artifactsname'
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

Note: branch name format: refs/heads/brachname
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature
